# Mounting issue while running vagrant up command

Tags: linux, vagrant

I am trying to run `vagrant up` command inside `~/Documents/Cyle-Rest` project and I get some issue with disk mounting which I am unable to resolve.

The issue is

> The following SSH Command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!
>
> mount -o 'ver=3,udp' 192.168.100.1:'/disk/owl/home/achha004/Documents/Cyle-Rest' /home/vagrant/sep-cyle-code
>
> Stdout from the command:
>
> Stderr from the command:
>
> mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 192.168.100.1:/disk/owl/home/achha004/Documents/Cyle-Rest

Answer (score 0):

Vagrant is trying to mount by default ([docs](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/)) your project directory as a `/Vagrant` to your virtual machine. It fails due to some permission issue on your host machine.

If you don't need it, you can disable mounting it by adding the following line to your Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.synced_folder '.', '/vagrant', disabled: true
```

Comment: No actually I have to mount it. And I also tried to run it through admin rights but it did not work even after that.